# How can the "Name" field in the node properties be useful for the user?

Tags: interface, node-editor, workflow

I understand blender needs to have a unique identifier for datablocks, but it's not like an "Object" were you can assign a different "Object Data" datablock. The node doesn't have access to other "Node Data" datablocks. How it can be useful for user to get access to this 'Name' field?

[image]
*User uses "Label" for naming nodes*

Comment: Was my answer helpful or did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'Name' field can be used to identify different nodes when accessing the nodes with python.

I might have 2 diffuse type nodes, 'Diffuse BSDF' and 'Diffuse BSDF.001' and be able to identify which node I want to change a property on, by it's name:

```
bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Diffuse BSDF'].use_custom_color
```

This would access the `use_custom_color` property on the node called "Diffuse BSDF".

I know which node I am accessing by looking at the 'Name' field in the node editor.

Because I am accessing the nodes by name, it might be useful for them to have more descriptive names to help me separate them from other nodes e.g. "diffuseMain", "diffuseOriginal' etc. I can use that name field to rename them to something more relevant and identifying.

Comment: Is there a way to shortcut the renaming of nodes? I really dislike having to use the sidepanel for that : (