# What is this node usually called?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm trying to find the Color Factor node shown below. It's typically already added in there attached to the Principled BSDF by default, but from time to time I have no idea where to find the node once I remove it. [image]

I'm on Blender 2.91.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Color MixRGB Shader Node**

[image]

Looks like a [*`Color > MixRGB`*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html)  shader  node.  Has its blend type set to "Multiply" and has been renamed to "Color Factor".

[image]

Comment: @vklidu  lol, did look up a rename link.. look familiar? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29085/how-can-the-name-field-in-the-node-properties-be-useful-for-the-user

Comment: You caught me :) Yes now I can look like a cleaver guy :) BTW this Q I remember very well (I was sure it is there for a reason), I was upset for its GUI and still I'm ... I can smell coders behind not an end-user :)